# Servlet redirection not working with combination of Apache Tomcat + Apache server

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to use `response.sendRedirect` in a servlet running on tomcat, which recieving requests from browser from apache server. So, any redirection replaces 'ip.ip.ip.ip' or 'someurl.com' part of url with 'localhost:8080' (as far as I can understand, it's because tomcat identifies the request source as the apache server address). `request.getRequestURL`is also affected by this problem. Is there any way to solve this problem without writing to response a javascript block that actualy should do redirection?

Comment: Show the code of the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: 
Configure the base url (from the browser point of view) in a property and then use this as the base url to redirect. In this case you could use something like:

```
response.sendRedirect(baseURLproperty + request.getRequestURI() + "?" + request.getQueryString())
```

More complex solution:
Since you are using apache as a reverse proxy you could configure it to add a custom request header with the original URL. Look at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Sorry, but the web application could run on a few different locations, so URL address could be different (and I prefer to find correct solution, just to make code cleaner). I found temporary solution in getting `request.getHeader("referer")` and "root" part of URL from it, but this only will work if I'm redirecting from one page in my application to other. About proxy - there is a lot in this web application that depends on current settings and I can't risk changing them (so I need Java-code solution).

Comment: Take care of the security implications of that! The header is easy to spoof/forge and can lead to a variety of attacks that leverage **"open redirect" vulnerability.** Try to validate the user input against a list of valid values before performing the redirect.